# Unable to login on cloudstack server

Tags: server

I installed cloudstack on Ubuntu, I made all the configurations but when opening Firefox I'm unable to connect to the server. 
The server address is 192.168.56.10
On the bar address of Firefox, I wrote:
192.168.56.10:8080/client
It doesn't load 
When I run the `cloudstack management status`, I have this:

```
sudo service cloudstack-management status
jsvc.exec[1128]: error occurred during initialization of VM
jsvc.exec[1128]: could not reserve enough space for object heap 
jsvc.exec[1128]: error occurred during initialization of VM
jsvc.exec[1128]: could not reserve enough space for object heap 
jsvc.exec[1128]: error occurred during initialization of VM
jsvc.exec[1128]: could not reserve enough space for object heap 
jsvc.exec[1128]: error occurred during initialization of VM
jsvc.exec[1128]: could not reserve enough space for object heap
jsvc.exec[1128]: error occurred during initialization of VM
jsvc.exec[1128]: could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps

service cloudstack-management status

service cloudstack-agent status

service tomcat6 status

service cloudstack-management stop

service tomcat6 stop

service cloudstack-agent stop

ps -efl | grep java

service cloudstack-management start

service cloudstack-management status

service cloudstack-agent start

service cloudstack-agent status

Comment: Already done,same results